# Shaders，Objects in the field of view are not drawn

Tags: three.js, shader

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>demo2</title>
    <style>
        body{ margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        #instructions{width:100%; height:100%; display:box; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); box-orient:horizontal; box-pack:center; box-align:center; text-align:center; font-size:20px; color:#fff; position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}
    </style>
    <script src="../lib/three.js-dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/stats.js-master/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/three.js-dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="instructions">Click start. The mouse adjusts the field of vision</div>
    
    
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        //scene
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //renderer
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            canvas: canvas
        });
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x4380CE, 1);
        //Ambient light
        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));
        //Camera
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
        camera.position.set(20, 7, 0);
        scene.add(camera);
        //OrbitControls.js for camera manipulation
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(5000));
        //stats
        const stats = new Stats();
        document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
        
        
        //
        var OperationTips = document.getElementById("instructions"), isMouseLocked = false;
        OperationTips.onclick = function() {
            OperationTips.requestPointerLock = OperationTips.requestPointerLock || OperationTips.mozRequestPointerLock || OperationTips.webkitRequestPointerLock;
            OperationTips.requestPointerLock();
        }
        document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', function() {
            if ( document.pointerLockElement === OperationTips || document.mozPointerLockElement === OperationTips || document.webkitPointerLockElement === OperationTips ) {
                OperationTips.style.display = 'none';
                isMouseLocked = true;
            } else {
                OperationTips.style.display = 'block';
                isMouseLocked = false;
            }
        }, false);
        //Adjustment Perspective
        var euler = new THREE.Euler(0, 0, 0, 'YXZ');
        var PI_2 = Math.PI / 2;
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if(isMouseLocked) {
                let movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
                let movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
                euler.setFromQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
                euler.y -= movementX * 0.002;
                euler.x -= movementY * 0.002;
                euler.x = Math.max(PI_2-Math.PI, Math.min(PI_2-0, euler.x));
                camera.quaternion.setFromEuler(euler);
            }
        });
        
        //****land************************************
        let land = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0x527715,
            //opacity: 0.9,
            //transparent: true
            //map: landTexture,
        }));
        land.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
        scene.add(land);


        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();



        //****grass***********************************
        var landWidth = 70;
        var landHeight = 40;
        var pos = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
        
        var grassVertexSource =`
            precision mediump float;
            attribute vec3 position;
            attribute vec3 normal;
            attribute vec3 offset;
            attribute vec2 uv;
            attribute vec2 halfRootAngle;
            attribute float scale;
            attribute float index;
            
            uniform float time;
            uniform float grassHeight;
        
            uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
            uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        
            varying vec2 vUv;
            varying vec3 vNormal;
            varying vec3 vPosition;
            varying float frc;
            varying float idx;
        
            //https://www.geeks3d.com/20141201/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-by-a-quaternion-in-glsl/
            vec3 rotateVectorByQuaternion(vec3 v, vec4 q) {
                return 2.0 * cross(q.xyz, v * q.w + cross(q.xyz, v)) + v;
            }
        
            void main() {
                //Vertex height in blade geometry
                frc = position.y / float(grassHeight);
        
                //Scale vertex
                vec3 vPosition = position;
                vPosition.y *= scale;
        
                //Invert scaling for normals
                vNormal = normal;
                vNormal.y /= scale;
        
                //Rotate the blade around the y-axis
                vec4 direction = vec4(0.0, halfRootAngle.x, 0.0, halfRootAngle.y);
                vPosition = rotateVectorByQuaternion(vPosition, direction);
                vNormal = rotateVectorByQuaternion(vNormal, direction);
        
                //UV for texture
                vUv = uv;
        
                vec3 pos;
                pos.x = offset.x;
                pos.y = offset.y;
                pos.z = offset.z;
        
                //Wind is a sine wave in time
                float noise = sin(0.1 * pos.x + time);
                float halfAngle = noise * 0.1;
                noise = 0.5 + 0.5 * cos(0.05 * pos.x + 0.25 * time);
                halfAngle -= noise * 0.1;
        
                direction = normalize(vec4(sin(halfAngle), 0.0, -sin(halfAngle), cos(halfAngle)));
        
                vPosition = rotateVectorByQuaternion(vPosition, direction);
                vNormal = rotateVectorByQuaternion(vNormal, direction);
        
                vPosition += pos;
        
                idx = index;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
            }
        `;
        
        var grassFragmentSource = `
            precision mediump float;
            uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
            
            //Light uniforms
            uniform float ambientStrength;
            uniform float diffuseStrength;
            uniform float specularStrength;
            uniform float translucencyStrength;
            uniform float shininess;
            uniform vec3 lightColour;
            uniform vec3 sunDirection;
            uniform vec3 grassColor;
            
            //Surface uniforms
            uniform sampler2D map;
            uniform sampler2D alphaMap;
            uniform vec3 specularColour;
        
            varying float frc;
            varying float idx;
            varying vec2 vUv;
            varying vec3 vNormal;
            varying vec3 vPosition;
        
            vec3 ACESFilm(vec3 x) {
                float a = 2.51;
                float b = 0.03;
                float c = 2.43;
                float d = 0.59;
                float e = 0.14;
                return clamp((x*(a*x+b))/(x*(c*x+d)+e), 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        
            void main() {
                //If it is transparent, it is not drawn
                if(texture2D(alphaMap, vUv).r < 0.15) {
                    discard;
                }
        
                vec3 normal;
                
                //Flip normals when viewing reverse of the blade
                if(gl_FrontFacing) {
                    normal = normalize(vNormal);
                } else {
                    normal = normalize(-vNormal);
                }
        
                //Get color data from texture
                vec3 textureColour = pow(texture2D(map, vUv).rgb, vec3(2.2));
        
                vec3 mixColour = idx > 0.75 ? vec3(0.07, 0.52, 0.06) : vec3(0.07, 0.43, 0.08);
                textureColour = mix(pow(mixColour, vec3(2.2)), textureColour, frc);
        
                vec3 lightTimesTexture = lightColour * textureColour;
                vec3 ambient = textureColour;
                vec3 lightDir = normalize(sunDirection);
        
                float dotNormalLight = dot(normal, lightDir);
                float diff = max(dotNormalLight, 0.0);
        
                //Color in light
                vec3 diffuse = diff * lightTimesTexture;
        
                float sky = max(dot(normal, vec3(0,1,0)), 0.0);
                vec3 skyLight = sky * vec3(0.12, 0.29, 0.55);
        
                vec3 viewDirection = normalize(cameraPosition - vPosition);
                vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDirection);
                
                //How many pieces are directly reflected on the camera
                float spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), shininess);
        
                vec3 specular = spec * specularColour * lightColour;
        
                //https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Translucent_Surfaces
                vec3 diffuseTranslucency = vec3(0);
                vec3 forwardTranslucency = vec3(0);
                float dotViewLight = dot(-lightDir, viewDirection);
                if(dotNormalLight <= 0.0) {
                    diffuseTranslucency = lightTimesTexture * translucencyStrength * -dotNormalLight;
                    if(dotViewLight > 0.0) {
                        forwardTranslucency = lightTimesTexture * translucencyStrength * pow(dotViewLight, 16.0);
                    }
                }
                vec3 col = 0.3 * skyLight * textureColour + ambientStrength * ambient + diffuseStrength * diffuse + specularStrength * specular + diffuseTranslucency + forwardTranslucency;
                
                //Tonemapping
                col = ACESFilm(col);
                
                //Gamma correction 1.0/2.2 = 0.4545...
                col = pow(col, vec3(0.4545));
                
                col = mix(vec3(0.0, 0.1, 0.0), col, frc);
                gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
            }
        `;
        
        var grass1Config = {
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            joints: 2,
            rotate: Math.PI/4,
            map: loader.load('https://al-ro.github.io/images/grass/blade_diffuse.jpg'),
            alphaMap: loader.load('https://al-ro.github.io/images/grass/blade_alpha.jpg'),
        }
        grass1Config['material'] = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: {
                time: { type:'float', value:0 },
                grassHeight: { type:'float', value:grass1Config.height },
                map: { value:grass1Config.map },
                alphaMap: { value:grass1Config.alphaMap },
                cameraPosition: { type:'vec3', value:camera.position },
                ambientStrength: { type:'float', value:0.6 },
                shininess: { type:'float', value:256 },
                //sunDirection: {type:'vec3', value:new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(2), Math.sin(0.25), -Math.cos(2))},
                //lightColour: { type:'vec3', value:new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) },
                //specularColour: { type:'vec3', value:new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) },
            },
            vertexShader: grassVertexSource,
            fragmentShader: grassFragmentSource,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        
        
        function addGrass(grassConfig, instances) {
            
            var grassBaseGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(grassConfig.width, grassConfig.height, 0, grassConfig.joints);
            grassBaseGeometry.translate(0, grassConfig.height/2, 0);
            
            //Curved grass grid for a more organic look
            let x, y, z, w, angle, sinAngle, rotationAngle;
            let vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
            let quaternion0 = new THREE.Quaternion();
            let quaternion1 = new THREE.Quaternion();
            
            angle = 0.05;
            sinAngle = Math.sin(angle / 2.0);
            rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            x = rotationAxis.x * sinAngle;
            y = rotationAxis.y * sinAngle;
            z = rotationAxis.z * sinAngle;
            w = Math.cos(angle / 2.0);
            quaternion0.set(x, y, z, w);
            
            angle = 0.3;
            sinAngle = Math.sin(angle / 2.0);
            rotationAxis.set(1, 0, 0);
            x = rotationAxis.x * sinAngle;
            y = rotationAxis.y * sinAngle;
            z = rotationAxis.z * sinAngle;
            w = Math.cos(angle / 2.0);
            quaternion1.set(x, y, z, w);
            
            quaternion0.multiply(quaternion1);
            
            angle = 0.1;
            sinAngle = Math.sin(angle / 2.0);
            rotationAxis.set(0, 0, 1);
            x = rotationAxis.x * sinAngle;
            y = rotationAxis.y * sinAngle;
            z = rotationAxis.z * sinAngle;
            w = Math.cos(angle / 2.0);
            quaternion1.set(x, y, z, w);
            
            quaternion0.multiply(quaternion1);
            let quaternion2 = new THREE.Quaternion();
            for (let v = 0; v < grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array.length; v += 3) {
                quaternion2.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), grassConfig.rotate);
                vertex.x = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v];
                vertex.y = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v + 1];
                vertex.z = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v + 2];
                let frac = vertex.y / grassConfig.height;
                quaternion2.slerp(quaternion0, frac);
                vertex.applyQuaternion(quaternion2);
                grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v] = vertex.x;
                grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v + 1] = vertex.y;
                grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position.array[v + 2] = vertex.z;
            }
            
            grassBaseGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
            grassBaseGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
            
            
            var offsets = [];
            var scales = [];
            var halfRootAngles = [];
            //var indices = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < instances; i++) {
                //Offset of grass root
                offsets.push(Math.random()*landWidth-landWidth/2, 0, Math.random()*landHeight-landHeight/2);
                //Randomly set the direction of the grass
                let angle = Math.PI - Math.random() * (2 * Math.PI);
                halfRootAngles.push(Math.sin(0.5 * angle), Math.cos(0.5 * angle));
                //Define variety in height
                if(i % 3 != 0) {
                    scales.push(2.0 + Math.random() * 1.25);
                } else {
                    scales.push(2.0 + Math.random());
                }
                //indices.push(i/instances);
            }
            var instancedGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
            instancedGeometry.index = grassBaseGeometry.index;
            instancedGeometry.attributes.position = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.position;
            instancedGeometry.attributes.uv = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.uv;
            instancedGeometry.attributes.normal = grassBaseGeometry.attributes.normal;
            instancedGeometry.setAttribute('offset', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(offsets), 3));
            instancedGeometry.setAttribute('scale', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(scales), 1));
            instancedGeometry.setAttribute('halfRootAngle', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(halfRootAngles), 2));
            //instancedGeometry.setAttribute('index', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(indices), 1));
            
            
            var grass = new THREE.Mesh(instancedGeometry, grassConfig.material);
            scene.add(grass);
        }

        addGrass(grass1Config, 1000);
        



        //************** Draw **************
        var time = 0;
        var lastFrame = Date.now();
        var thisFrame;

        function draw() {
            stats.begin();

            //Update time
            thisFrame = Date.now();
            time += (thisFrame - lastFrame) / 500;
            lastFrame = thisFrame;
            grass1Config.material.uniforms.time.value = time;

            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            stats.end();
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
        draw();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put a piece of grass in the scene, but when I adjust the view and move the center of the grass out of the view, the whole grass disappears. I know it's because three.js I don't want to render things outside the perspective, but actually there are some grass in the perspective. How can I render the whole grassland as long as there is grass in the perspective?

Comment: Try `grass.frustumCulled = false;`.

Comment: thank you。But in this way, even if the object is outside the view angle, it will be rendered. Will there be a certain performance impact